# Tracking points separately using openCV

Tags: opencv, video, tracking

I am trying to track 3 points in a video ...... 
I have videos for x-ray images ... and these 3 points are moved on frames.

I am trying to let the user select the 3 points in the first frame ... and I want to track each point separately...  these 3 points will not move together as an object ... each one has different movement.

my question is , how can I let the user select these 3 points in the first frame ,, then track them (I want the coordinates for each point in each frame)...

I need suggestion method to I do it .... 
I have image that show the points that I want to track ... but I do not know how can I upload it

thanks in advance

Comment: have a look at the LK Optical Flow sample maybe ?

Comment: do you mean Lucas–Kanade method optical flow?

Comment: yup, I remember there was a sample that shipped with OpenCV which allows you to click on a region and track it

Comment: The motion that I am trying to track has weak feature , we cannot see big different in the color between the points that I am interesting to track and surrounding pixels .... I could not upload images to describe what I mean , but I am tying to track 3 points has weak features !!! ... how can I do it

Comment: is there any other way to track the points rather than Optical flow LK ?

Comment: yup, although I haven't played with others myself. You can have a look in the [OpenCV Docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html): check out `calcOpticalFlowSF` or `calcOpticalFlowFarneback` for example